# Polynomial whose roots are some of the Nth-roots of unity.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

I have to compute the following quantity

\begin{align}
   \prod_{\alpha\neq\beta=0}^{N-1} \left(1-e^{2\pi i \frac{\alpha-\beta}{aN}}\right)\label{a}\tag{1}
\end{align}

where $a$ is a natural number, or alternatively the quantity

\begin{equation}
   \prod_{\alpha=0}^{N-1} \left(x-e^{2\pi i \frac{\alpha}{aN}}\right)\label{b}\tag{2}
\end{equation}

that is in other words the polynomial whose roots are the first $N$ among the $(aN)^{th}$-roots of unity.

I would like to know if there is some closed form expression for these quantities. The thing I know is that if I run the product over the whole set of the $(aN)^{th}$-roots of unity I have

\begin{equation}
   \prod_{\alpha=0}^{aN-1} \left(x-e^{2\pi i \frac{\alpha}{aN}}\right) = x^{aN}-1\label{c}\tag{3}
\end{equation}

for the second quantity and accordingly

\begin{gather}
   \prod_{\alpha\neq\beta=0}^{aN-1} \left(1-e^{2\pi i \frac{\alpha-\beta}{aN}}\right) = \left.\frac{\prod_{\alpha,\beta=0}^{aN-1} \left(x-e^{2\pi i \frac{\alpha-\beta}{aN}}\right)}{(x-1)^{aN}}\right|_{x=1} = \left.\left(\frac{(x^{aN}-1)}{x-1}\right)^{aN}\right|_{x=1} = (aN)^{aN}\label{d}\tag{4}
\end{gather}

for the first one. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: In what sense do you want to know the polynomial? It's coefficients will lie in a cyclotomic field. How do you want them presented? Do you want their minpolys?

Comment: I would like to know if either there is an explicit form as in the known case where you get $x^{aN}-1$, or in terms of some known special polynomial. Sorry if I was not clear but I am a physicicst, so not that much expert in all the mathematical tools.

Comment: Are you strictly interested in explicit formulas or just in asymptotics for special values of $x$ and large values of $N$? The latter can be way easier to obtain.

Comment: What examples have you computed?

Comment: We are interested in (1) (i.e. $x=1$ after some manipulations of (2)) and large $N$. We would like to extract the exact $\mathcal{O}(N^2)$ part if there is one. If not, we would like a rigorous demonstration that it is $\mathcal{O}(N\log N)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left\|\prod_{k=0}^{N-1}\left(1-\exp\frac{2\pi i k}{a N}\right)\right\|=2^N\prod_{k=0}^{N-1}\sin\frac{\pi k}{a N}=2^N\exp\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\log\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{a}\cdot\frac{k}{N}\right) $$
and by Riemann sums
$$ \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\log\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{a}\cdot\frac{k}{N}\right)\approx \int_{0}^{1}\log\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{a}\right)\,dx=\log\frac{\pi}{a}+O\left(\frac{1}{a^2}\right) $$
so
$$ \log\left\|\prod_{k=0}^{N-1}\left(1-\exp\frac{2\pi i k}{a N}\right)\right\|\ll N\log\left(\frac{2\pi}{a}\right). $$

Comment: Is there some trouble in $\log\sin(\frac{\pi}{a}\cdot\frac{k}{N})$ when $k=0$ since it is not defined? Can you give a bound for the error in approximating the Riemann sum by that integral, especially if the function blows up at $x=0$ ?

Comment: @super_waqas: all right, I will provide an update as soon as I have enough spare time.

Comment: The point of manipulating (2) before putting x=1 is that if one immidiately puts x=1 he will get immediately zero!